# Pokemon go login question

Tags: pokemon-go

I originally opened an account with a login name and password. I logged out to try and start a different account for my son. When I start the game now it only gives me the option to sign up with google. How do I log in with my original account info?

Comment: Did you use a Trainer account, or a Google account to start?

Comment: A quick note that Niantic will flag multiple accounts on one phone as "suspicious." They're very big on the One Account, One Phone, One Person rule.

Comment: Side note: This question appears to be asked when there was some issues with the Trainer Club account not appearing on iOS.  It's been fixed since.